# Extract string from value and insert into field

Tags: mysql, substring

This is mytable:

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | DA-1111 A   |  
|  2 | DA-5334 B   |  
|  3 | DA-4532 A   |  
|  4 | DA-34 K     |  
+----+-------------+
```

With query:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(myfield, '-', -1), ' ', 1) as colB from mytable
```

I get extraced values between DA- and last letter. Now I want extract value from field and in the same time insert that value into new field in the same table. The final result should be:

```
+----+-------------+------+  
| id | data        | colB |
+----+-------------+------+  
|  1 | DA-1111 A   | 1111 |  
|  2 | DA-5334 B   | 5334 | 
|  3 | DA-4532 A   | 4532 | 
|  4 | DA-34 K     | 34   | 
+----+-------------+------+
```

Is that possible and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
update mytable
set colB = substring_index(substring_index(myfield, '-', -1), ' ', 1)
```

Of course the table should already have a field named `colB`, otherwise you can create it with an `ALTER TABLE` statement.